# Как изменить размеры формы CollectionEditor

Tags: winforms, vb.net, propertygrid

Имеется кастомный редактор коллекций наследуемый от `CollectionEditor`

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class MyCollectionEditor
    Inherits CollectionEditor

    Public Sub New(ByVal type As Type)
        MyBase.New(type)
    End Sub



    Public Shared Event MyFormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)


    Protected Overrides Function CreateInstance(itemType As Type) As Object

        Dim instance = MyBase.CreateInstance(itemType)

        Return instance

    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function SetItems(ByVal editValue As Object, ByVal value() As Object) As Object

        If TypeOf editValue Is List(Of ExFieldJoin) Then

            Dim parent As ExTableJoin = Me.Context.Instance

            For Each item As ExFieldJoin In value
                item.TableName = parent.TableName
            Next

        End If

        Return MyBase.SetItems(editValue, value)

    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function CreateCollectionForm() As CollectionForm

        Dim collectionForm As CollectionForm = MyBase.CreateCollectionForm()
        AddHandler collectionForm.FormClosed, AddressOf CollectionFormClosed
        Return collectionForm

    End Function

    Private Sub CollectionFormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent MyFormClosed(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Не могу понять каким образом добраться до свойств редактора коллекции, например поменять его размеры и цвет фона.

Пробовал делать это в `CreateCollectionForm` но результаты оказались глючными.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Добавляем обработчик события `Load` и в нем получаем доступ к форме коллекции типа `CollectionEditor.CollectionForm`

```
''' <summary>
''' Перекрытый метод создания формы редактора - для сохранения/восстановления
''' размеров и положения окна
''' </summary>
Protected Overrides Function CreateCollectionForm() As CollectionForm

    Dim collectionForm As CollectionForm = MyBase.CreateCollectionForm()

    ' Подключаем свой обработчик открытия
    AddHandler collectionForm.Load, AddressOf MyFormLoad

    Return collectionForm

End Function


Protected Sub MyFormLoad(sender As CollectionEditor.CollectionForm, e As EventArgs)
    sender.Size = New Drawing.Size(600, 450)
End Sub
```